# Unfamiliar Python syntax (e.g. obj1 = <class method>(<method parameters>)(obj2))

Tags: python, syntax

I'm taking an AI / ML online course, and some of the assignments include Python language phrases like:

```
input_img = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
Z1 = tfl.Conv2D(8, kernel_size=4,strides=(1,1), padding='SAME')(input_img)
```

It seems that the general syntax of the second line is:

```
obj1 = <class method>(<method parameters>)(obj2),
```

where obj1, obj2 are some class instances.

Could not find an explanation to this syntax.
Please direct me to a reference / example clarifying said syntax.

Comment: If `x(y)` returns a function (something callable), `x(y)(z)` calls the returned function. It's normal Python function-call syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Did not understand that a callable method is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is that `tfl.Conv2D(8, kernel_size=4,strides=(1,1), padding='SAME')` returns something that is callable, like a callable object OR a method, then you call it with `input_img` params

---

A simple example

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.values = list(args)

    def run(self, *more_values):
        print(f"A.run with {self.values} - {more_values}")

class B:
    @staticmethod
    def get_method(a, b, c):
        return A(a, b, c).run
```

In the case `B.get_method()` returns a `run` method that is not called, so when retrieving it, you can call it, and split in 2 steps to understand better

```
B.get_method(1, 2, 3)(4, 5)  # A.run with [1, 2, 3] - (4, 5)

my_method = B.get_method(1, 2, 3)
my_method(4, 5)  # A.run with [1, 2, 3] - (4, 5)
```